# Q-How to fill a new column in data.frame based on row values by two conditions in R

Tags: r, loops, group-by, dataset

I am trying to figure out how to generate a new column in R that accounts for whether a politician "i" remains in the same party or defect for a given legislatures "l". These politicians and parties are recognized because of indexes. Here is an example of how my data originally looks like:

```
## example of data

names <- c("Jesus Martinez", "Anrita blabla", "Paco Pico", "Reiner Steingress", "Jesus Martinez Porras")
Parti.affiliation <- c("Winner","Winner","Winner", "Loser", NA)#NA, "New party", "Loser", "Winner", NA
Legislature <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5), rep(5,5), rep(6,5))
selection <- c(rep("majority", 15), rep("PR", 15))
sex<- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male")
Election<- c(rep(1955, 5), rep(1960, 5), rep(1965, 5), rep(1970,5), rep(1975,5), rep(1980,5))

d<- data.frame(names =factor(rep(names, 6)), party.affiliation = c(rep(Parti.affiliation,5), NA, "New party", "Loser", "Winner", NA), legislature = Legislature, selection = selection, gender =rep(sex, 6), Election.date = Election)

## genrating id for politician and party.affiliation

d$id_pers<- paste(d$names, sep="")
d <- arrange(d, id_pers)
d <- transform(d, id_pers = as.numeric(factor(id_pers)))
d$party.affiliation1<- as.numeric(d$party.affiliation)
```

The expected outcome should show the following: if a politician (showed through the column "id_pers") has changed their values in the column "party.affiliation1", a value 1 will be assigned in a new column called "switch", otherwise 0. The same procedure should be done with every politician in the dataset, so the expected outcome should be like this:

```
d["switch"]<- c(1, rep(0,4), NA, rep(0,6), rep(NA, 6),1, rep(0,5), rep (0,5),1) # 0= remains in the same party / 1= switch party affiliation.
```

As example, you can see in this data.frame that the first politician, called "Anrita blabla", was a candidate of the party '3' from the 1st to 5th legislature. However, we can observe that "Anrita" changes her party affiliation in the 6th legislature, so she was a candidate for the party '2'. Therefore, the new column "switch" should contain a value '1' to reflect this Anrita's change of party affiliation, and '0' to show that "Anrita" did not change her party affiliation for the first 5 legislatures.

I have tried several approaches to do that (e.g. loops). I have found this strategy the simplest one, but it does not work :(

```
## add a new column based on raw values 
  ind <- c(FALSE, party.affiliation1[-1L]!= party.affiliation1[-length(party.affiliation1)] & party.affiliation1!= 'Null')
  d <- d %>% group_by(id_pers) %>% mutate(this = ifelse(ind, 1, 0))
```

I hope you find this explanation clear. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
d%>%
  group_by(id_pers)%>%
  mutate(switch=as.numeric((party.affiliation1-lag(party.affiliation1)!=0)))
```

The  first entry will be NA as we don't have information on whether their previous, if any, party affiliation was different.

**Edit:** We use the `default=` parameter of `lag()` with `ifelse()` nested to differentiate the first values.

```
df=d%>%
  group_by(id_pers)%>%
  mutate(switch=ifelse((party.affiliation1-lag(party.affiliation1,default=-99))>90,99,ifelse(party.affiliation1-lag(party.affiliation1)!=0,1,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jaime Caffarel and @Haboryme. Nevertheless, let me ask you whether it is posible in your line of code to say to R: "assign a value 99 to those first entries". In this way, I can differentiate between those real missing values and those cases, which I have information about their party affiliation. =)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table
d <- as.data.table(d)

# Order by election date
d <- d[order(Election.date)]

# Get the previous affiliation, for each id_pers
d[, previous_party_affiliation := shift(party.affiliation), by = id_pers]

# If the current affiliation is different from the previous one, set to 1
d[, switch := ifelse(party.affiliation != previous_party_affiliation, 1, 0)] 

# Remove the column
d[, previous_party_affiliation := NULL]
```

As Haboryme has pointed out, the first entry of each person will be NA, due to the lack of information on previous elections. And the result would give this:

```
                    names party.affiliation legislature selection gender Election.date id_pers party.affiliation1 switch
 1:         Anrita blabla            Winner           1  majority Female          1955       1                 NA     NA
 2:         Anrita blabla            Winner           2  majority Female          1960       1                 NA      0
 3:         Anrita blabla            Winner           3  majority Female          1965       1                 NA      0
 4:         Anrita blabla            Winner           4        PR Female          1970       1                 NA      0
 5:         Anrita blabla            Winner           5        PR Female          1975       1                 NA      0
 6:         Anrita blabla         New party           6        PR Female          1980       1                 NA      1
```

(...)

EDITED

In order to identify the first entry of the political affiliation and assign the value 99 to them, you can use this modified version:

```
# Note the "fill" parameter passed to the function shift
d[, previous_party_affiliation := shift(party.affiliation, fill = "First"), by = id_pers]

# Set 99 to the first occurrence
d[, switch := ifelse(party.affiliation != previous_party_affiliation, ifelse(previous_party_affiliation == "First", 99, 1), 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JaimeCaffarel!! Nevertheless, can you find an answer for my question in the comment below the Haborymes answer?

Comment: thanks a lot!!! I did not know the data.table package, so I have learnt a lot with your post.Nevertheless, I will use the other option because I am more familiar with dplyr gramar :)  I will take it into account the data.table package in the future. Once again, thanks a lot for your effort!!